# Writing Java with Netbeans Issue

Tags: java, netbeans

I am looking for an in-depth explanation for the following school project that I am attempting to (and failing terribly at) understand. The assignment is to use Netbeans IDE Java EE (Installed Glassfish Server with it, so I am hoping to use that) to create a simply Store locator web app that interfaces with Best Buy's API BBYOpen.

To my current understanding I need to create a .jsp file that will house the intial HTML form that will allow a user to input their zipcode and a distance radius, in order to find the Best Buy Store locations closest to the input zipcode. As well as a servlet that will handle the form data capture and pass it through to the Best Buy API.

On a final note, I am learning this web development without much experience, and I realize that many of you have vast amounts more experience than myself, so if anyone could provide me with a detailed (i.e. For a dummy) explanation of how I might go about doing this, I would very much appreciate it.

Thanks and Best Wishes

Comment: Can you explain which programming parts you are having trouble with and some us that part of the code?  We can't really explain the requirements to you....that's your professor's job.  But we can help with code and design.

Comment: You should be able to just make a `Java Web` - `Web Application` with Netbeans. Which should set everything up for you. Then create a jsp webpage that both generates a form and handles the form submission

Comment: Try stepping back a bit and instead of looking at the entire project take it in steps. First you know you need a server, so look online at how to get a glassfish server installed. Then you know you need a jsp and servlet, find a tutorial on how to get that framework up and running, there are a ton of tutorials online and probably even some sample environments you can unzip into your project. Just remember 1 step at a time, dont get caught up in the large and seemingly overwhelming scope.

Comment: The programming portion that I am having problems with is more along the building of the servlet to "query" the Best Buy API. I am familiar with building the HTML Form, but attempting to capture the data in a .java file is one thing that I cannot seem to figure out. We did a Netbeans tutorial on RESTful Web Services, but it only explained how to build a java web app using a local database, not on how to build anything to connect to an API. I sort of feel left out in the dark..."Here's a tutorial on this, now do that"

Comment: @LoganMurphy - I have used the Java Web - Web Application in Netbeans to give me a skeleton. My problem is figuring out the code to handle the form submission. I had just finished up doing the same project using Apache and PHP. Java has a bit more going on to it, that PHP, it seems.

Comment: You do not need a servlet. you can write code in JSP just like you would in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install apache from here http://tomcat.apache.org/

Open Netbeans.

Go to File -> New Project -> Java Web -> Web Application

Click Next (Initialization will begin).

Name your project and select the location of project related folders.

Click Next.

Click Add (Next to server) -> Choose Apache Tomcat -> Choose the location (C:/path/to/tomcat) -> Specify Username and Password and create the user if it does not exist -> Finish -> Finish

This will generate a project for you.

Delete index.html

Create index.jsp and enter this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Zip Code</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="index.jsp">
            <input type="text" name="zipcode"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
        </form>
        <%
            String zipcode = request.getParameter("zipcode");
            if (zipcode != null) {
                out.print("Wow you live at " + zipcode + "!");
            }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Press play and you are on your way to learning JSP

In the future your code might look something more like this but I don't know exactly (note that this code will not compile as it, but it may aid you in finding what you need from the API)

```
<%@page import="org.bestbuy.BBYOpen" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Zip Code</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="index.jsp">
            <input type="text" name="zipcode"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
        </form>
        <%
            String zipcode = request.getParameter("zipcode");
            if (zipcode != null) {
                out.print("Wow you live at " + zipcode + "!");
                BBYOpen bbyo = new BBYOpen();
                Store[] stores = bbyo.getStoreByZipCode(zipcode);
                for (Store store : stores) {
                    out.print(store.getInfo());
                }
            }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Brilliant! So far this works exactly. So in effect this is the form (Which I can alter to suit my project). Now my next objective is to figure out how to have this query the BestBuy API. Does that require a separate file/class. The BestBuy documentation explains this. Is this what I need to tweak around to get the results I need? [link]http://code.google.com/p/remix-java/ I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I will leave it up to you to discover how to use the API but I gave some code that may give you an idea what to look for in the API. Although it would be good practice you do not need to create your own classes. You can just import the Best Buy API to this page and reference it in this page.

Comment: For example I should load 'import com.mattwilliamsnyc.service.remix.*;'in as opposed to '<%@page import="org.bestbuy.BBYOpen" %>', at least to import the API? Sorry, completely thrilled that I am getting any sort of help.

Comment: That is absolutely correct. As well as use the proper classes and methods associated with them.

Comment: One last question, I promise. I have the Remix.java files downloaded. Is there a way in NetBeans that I can added them to the project?

Comment: Yes, with Windows Explorer, navigate to the `Remix.java\src` folder and you will find the `com` folder. Drag it directly from your Windows Explorer to your `Source Packages` folder in Netbeans and everything should fit in nicely (make sure you extract first)